# Problems creating JAXBContext to marshal object as XML

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a complicated JAXB data structure generated from an XML schema. I would like to marshal it as XML solely for the purpose of logging the event. With the problems I'm having I would appreciate other solutions for this use case, but in any even here's what's wrong:

I've found the following solution:

```
SomeClass object;
java.io.StringWriter msg = new java.io.StringWriter();
javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext context = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class);
javax.xml.bind.Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
// Create a root element since the object is not the root element.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<SomeClass> tolog = new javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<SomeClass>(
    new javax.xml.namespace.QName("SomeClass"), SomeClass.class, object);
marshaller.marshal(tolog, msg);
// Output msg somewhere, like sysout:
System.out.println(msg.toString());
```

I've tried this two ways, each of which caused its own error.

1. I created the JAXBContext object in static context to avoid recreating it every time. This seemed to mess with the class registry somehow because only if I called `JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class)` in static time, I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to instantiate custom classes.
2. I created the JAXBContext object when first needed (which is inside an EJB's method that takes the JAXB object as an argument), storing it to a static variable after the first time. This time, the call to `JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class)` threw the following exception:

   ```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: mypackage._1.NameType$JaxbAccessorF_value cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.instanciate(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:199)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:191)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:282)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.<init>(TransducedAccessor.java:237)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:177)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.calcTransducer(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:245)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getTransducer(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:219)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.link(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:196)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.link(ModelBuilder.java:399)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.link(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:138)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:464)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1163)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:236)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:172)
     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:132)
     at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:334)
     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:431)
     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:394)
     at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:298)
     at mypackage.MainBean.SOAPCall(MainBean.java:108)
   ```

I've received a request for the dependency tree. Here it is:

```
[INFO] mypackage:Main:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- mypackage:datatypes:jar:1.0.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.openejb:javaee-api:jar:6.0-5:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.openejb:tomee-embedded:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-jsf:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-impl:jar:1.1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.sf.scannotation:scannotation:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.myfaces.core:myfaces-api:jar:2.1.7:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.openejb.patch:openejb-openwebbeans-jsf:jar:1.1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-core:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:mbean-annotation-api:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-api:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-loader:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-javaagent:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-jee:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:kahadb:jar:5.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-ra:jar:5.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:jar:5.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activeio-core:jar:3.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.components:geronimo-connector:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.6_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.components:geronimo-transaction:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.objectweb.howl:howl:jar:1.0.1-1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.javamail:geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm-shaded:jar:3.10:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb.patch:xbean-finder-shaded:jar:3.10:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.10:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-naming:jar:3.10:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-bundleutils:jar:3.10:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.swizzle:swizzle-stream:jar:1.6.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-spi:jar:1.1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-ejb:jar:1.1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-ee:jar:1.1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-ee-common:jar:1.1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-web:jar:1.1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.openejb.patch:openjpa-asm-shaded:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.sourceforge.serp:serp:jar:1.13.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.bval:bval-core:jar:0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.bval:bval-jsr303:jar:0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.myfaces.core:myfaces-impl:jar:2.1.7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-api:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-util:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ha:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-tribes:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-coyote:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jsp-api:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-el-api:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper-el:jar:7.0.27:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:3.5.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-deployment_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-client:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.openejb:tomee-catalina:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.openejb:javaee-api:jar:tomcat:6.0-3:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.openejb:tomee-common:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.openejb:tomee-loader:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |     |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-server:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.openejb:openejb-ejbd:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.openejb:openejb-http:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
```

What is going wrong, and how do I make it go right instead?

Comment: Which app server are you in?  Are you packaging any of the JAXB jars in with your ear/war?

Comment: This runs on TomEE+, but I am getting these errors during the test phase of the maven build process. The test phase instantiates the class and injects other beans manually. I'm not sure if the JAXB jars are packaged in my `war`.

Comment: Check out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569395/netbeans-with-jaxb-random-classcastexception-cannot-be-cast-to-com-sun-xml-bin

Comment: Well that worked but it was incredibly unsatisfying. What does that even do? And why is it a problem in the first place?

Comment: This looks like a classpath problem. Could you please post `mvn dependency:tree` log? I believe you may have different, possibly incompatible versions of JAXB jars.

Comment: Posted the output of that command (with custom package and class names modified, as in the rest of my question).